# Office 2010 Migration to Office 2016

Tags: vba

In Office 2010 and 2007 I had several VBA programs where I would click on a desktop icon to run the program.  When the program opened it would automatically display a menu (Menu.Show).  I have migrated to Office 2016 (no code changes), and now I get a flashing icon in the tray instead of the menu being displayed.  If I click on the flashing icon, then the menu displays.  How do I get the menu to display automatically?.

Comment: Perhaps adding [`ThisWorkbook.Activate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-activate-method-excel) to the macro would help? What is the target of the desktop shortcut?

Comment: The dialog apparently isn't showing top-most. Either you need to add some code to make it so, or wait until Microsoft pushes an update that fixes this. Did you report it to UserVoice? Sent them a "frown" with a comment to that effect? They can't fix what they don't know is broken - also, seeing the code you're using to display that form could help us help you. `Menu.Show` doesn't tell us anything about what you're doing - not without assuming a ton of things.